# fs.stat not calling callback on Windows

Tags: node.js, fs, winston

I have a node application that uses the Winston logging library and it is failing at a call to fs.stat in the Winston file transport code. The code in question is (file.js around lines 515-536):

```
console.log("fullname = " + fullname);

fs.stat(fullname, function (err, stats) {
  console.log("CALLBACK");
  if (err) {
    if (err.code !== 'ENOENT') {
      return self.emit('error', err);
    }

    return createAndFlush(0);
  }

  if (!stats || (self.maxsize && stats.size >= self.maxsize)) {
    //
    // If `stats.size` is greater than the `maxsize` for
    // this instance then try again
    //
    return checkFile(self._getFile(true));
  }

  createAndFlush(stats.size);
});
```

I have added the console.log calls.  The first on prints at the first logging event but the second one is never reached.

The application is running under Node.js 0.10.10 on Windows 7 32-bit.  It works on Linux.
The application's http server continues to service events so the main event loop is OK.

The following short application runs correctly for a file that exists and one that doesn't:

```
fs = require('fs');

fs.stat('c:\\apiserver\\v8.log', function(err, st) {
    console.dir(err);
    console.dir(st);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem seems to arise where the log call occurs in the error handler of a domain.  Domains are experimental so I guess I shouldn't be too surprised.  The fix is to explicitly trap the error (in this case arising from JSON.parse("rubbish text")) and call log from the catch block.  The call to log is still within the scope of the domain so that, of itself, is not a problem.